# Data Re-formatting from d.hh:mm:ss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set with a strange format as shown below which i need to convert to HH:MM:SS format

Sample Data:

Format is Day.hour:minute:second - it is a string

01.15:00:15 - Expect Output 39:00:15

00.05:01:00 - Expect Output 05:01:00

02.00:10:15 - Expect Output 48:10:15

I have tried this code below,

```
=24*LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1)+MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-2-LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,":","@",2))))-LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1)))&":"&TEXT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,":","@",2))),"00")
```

This is the Output i get for example 1 after i manually change the "." between day's and hours to a ":"

Output -
39:00

Comment: What have you tried? If it is not just a string and was previously set up as a custom format, then just select the cells, right click and select "Format cells..." and change the format there.

Answer (score 1):

You overcomplicated the matter. Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXT(--LEFT(A1,2)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,4,8)),"[HH]:MM:SS")
```

Though, these are yet again text values looking like timevalues. So you could also leave out the `TEXT()` function and custom format your cell to keep the numeric value.